# first rails database cant go live heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

i am completely lost ive been at it for hours and really dont know what to do here

```
2022-07-31T05:02:04.598119+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=railsfriendsjerome.herokuapp.com request_id=80b50c42-8d66-4812-985d-d4a48496dd7c fwd="60.139.38.29" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-31T05:02:05.825237+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=railsfriendsjerome.herokuapp.com request_id=8596d4af-7289-44ef-8f42-e665d33246b9 fwd="60.139.38.29" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-31T05:03:12.012838+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=railsfriendsjerome.herokuapp.com request_id=71622dbd-714c-414a-baee-5b29ae810417 fwd="60.139.38.29" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-31T05:03:13.146209+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=railsfriendsjerome.herokuapp.com request_id=e76e09bb-e948-452e-98a0-0208296aaeb1 fwd="60.139.38.29" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Answer (score 0):

A long guess is that you haven't run the migrations in heroku's remote database. Try something like `heroku run rails db:migrate -a railsfriendsjerome` (you will need heroku login before that).

Comment: thanks i got a pop up saying my app was live after i ran that command but i still get an application error here are the logs

Comment: 2022-08-01T01:43:52.654066+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `rails db:migrate` by user jeromepchallet@gmail.com
2022-08-01T01:43:55.274102+00:00 heroku[run.4695]: Awaiting client
2022-08-01T01:43:55.288849+00:00 heroku[run.4695]: Starting process with command `rails db:migrate`
2022-08-01T01:43:55.374831+00:00 heroku[run.4695]: State changed from starting to up
2022-08-01T01:44:00.967940+00:00 heroku[run.4695]: Process exited with status 1
2022-08-01T01:44:01.144612+00:00 heroku[run.4695]: State changed from up to complete

Comment: 2022-08-01T01:44:15.532040+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=railsfriendsjerome.herokuapp.com request_id=3f1c3e1c-42b8-4961-9c22-c80ca99d617c fwd="60.139.38.29" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-08-01T01:44:16.920587+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=railsfriendsjerome.herokuapp.com request_id=a7b2c8fc-7be8-4445-ae12-3e166d95f31a fwd="60.139.38.29" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Comment: It could be many things. From assets compile, rails missing route path, a bug somewhere up to the database configuration. Are you sure it works in development? Try to connect from your local to the database. Check to see if it has recognized the necessary buildpacks. Try `heroku run rails console` and see if it connects in the console.

Comment: thanks here is the log after i ran heroku run rails console

Comment: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.0/lib/zeitwerk/loader/callbacks.rb:25:in `on_file_autoloaded': expected file /app/app/new/controllers/application_controller.rb to define constant Controllers::ApplicationController, but didn't (Zeitwerk::NameError)

      raise Zeitwerk::NameError.new("expected file #{file} to define constant #{cpath}, but didn't", cref.last)
      ^^^^^

Comment: the code worked well locally on my computer

Comment: Seems like somewhere there is a wrong path for application_controller? It says it can't find `/app/app/new/controllers/application_controller.rb`, check this double /app in the path. In production it loads all the files, so if there is a bug or an error somewhere, then it will raise it. This isn't the case in development where it loads the files based on the use of them. Add this `config.eager_load = true` inside `environments/development.rb` and you will see the error.